# Конвертация массива в JSON

Tags: php, json

Всем доброго дня. Пытаюсь сделать клавиатуру с помощью API VK, по их [методчике](https://vk.com/dev/bots_docs_3), но что-то не получается. Пробую перевести массив в JSON, но не выходит, выдает ошибку "Function name must be a string", хотя вроде все делаю верно.

Код на PHP:

```
$array_keyboard_data = array(
"one_time"=>"false",
"buttons"=>array(
   array(
      array(
         "action"=>array(
            "type"=>"text",
            "payload"=>"{\"button\":\"1"}",
            "label"=>"Red"),
         "color"=>"negative"),
      array(
         "action"=>array(
            "type"=>"text",
            "payload"=>"{\"button\":\"2\"}",
            "label"=>"Green"),
         "color"=> "positive")),
   array(
      array(
         "action"=>array(
            "type"=>"text",
            "payload"=>"{\"button\":\"3\"}",
            "label"=>"White"),
         "color"=>"default"),
     array(
         "action"=>array(
            "type"=>"text",
            "payload"=>"{\"button\":\"4\"}",
            "label"=>"Blue"),
          "color"=>"primary")
       )
    ));

$jsoncode = $json_encode($array_keyboard_data);

echo $jsoncode;
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
{
"one_time": false,
"buttons": [
  [{
    "action": {
      "type": "text",
      "payload": "{\"button\": \"1\"}",
      "label": "Red"
    },
    "color": "negative"
  },
 {
    "action": {
      "type": "text",
      "payload": "{\"button\": \"2\"}",
      "label": "Green"
    },
    "color": "positive"
  }],
  [{
    "action": {
      "type": "text",
      "payload": "{\"button\": \"3\"}",
      "label": "White"
    },
    "color": "default"
  },
 {
    "action": {
      "type": "text",
      "payload": "{\"button\": \"4\"}",
      "label": "Blue"
    },
    "color": "primary"
  }]
]
}
```

Плюс хотелось бы узнать, верно ли я составил массив для конвертации, может это можно как-то сократить для удобства?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Пробую перевести массив в JSON, но не выходит, выдает ошибку "Function name must be a string", хотя вроде все делаю верно.

Забыли `\` в одной из строк:

```html
<?php

    $array_keyboard_data = array(
"one_time"=>"false",
"buttons"=>array(
   array(
      array(
         "action"=>array(
            "type"=>"text",
            "payload"=>"{\"button\":\"1\"}", // \ <---
            "label"=>"Red"),
         "color"=>"negative"),
      array(
         "action"=>array(
            "type"=>"text",
            "payload"=>"{\"button\":\"2\"}",
            "label"=>"Green"),
         "color"=> "positive")),
   array(
      array(
         "action"=>array(
            "type"=>"text",
            "payload"=>"{\"button\":\"3\"}",
            "label"=>"White"),
         "color"=>"default"),
     array(
         "action"=>array(
            "type"=>"text",
            "payload"=>"{\"button\":\"4\"}",
            "label"=>"Blue"),
          "color"=>"primary")
       )
    ));

    echo json_encode($array_keyboard_data);

?>
```

Результат:

```js
{
  "one_time": "false",
  "buttons": [
    [{
      "action": {
        "type": "text",
        "payload": "{\"button\":\"1\"}",
        "label": "Red"
      },
      "color": "negative"
    }, {
      "action": {
        "type": "text",
        "payload": "{\"button\":\"2\"}",
        "label": "Green"
      },
      "color": "positive"
    }],
    [{
      "action": {
        "type": "text",
        "payload": "{\"button\":\"3\"}",
        "label": "White"
      },
      "color": "default"
    }, {
      "action": {
        "type": "text",
        "payload": "{\"button\":\"4\"}",
        "label": "Blue"
      },
      "color": "primary"
    }]
  ]
}
```

---

- [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php)  — Возвращает JSON-представление данных